Sql query result in a single row with multiple dynamic columns
i have multiple rows and want to make dynamic column i tried below code with case it work fine but i need the column to be dynamic based on the count of max Code



EventId
Code
Date




1
A12
12/12/2020


1
A13
12/12/2020


2
A12
12/12/2020


2
A13
12/12/2020


3
A13
12/12/2020



i want it like below table



EventId
Code1
Date1
Code2
Date2




1
A12
12/12/2020
A13
12/12/2020


2
A12
12/12/2020
A13
12/11/2020


3
A13
12/12/2021





 
WITH Ranked AS (
    SELECT
        EventID,
        Date,
        Code 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  EventID ORDER BY Date)
    FROM TableEvent
)
SELECT
    EventID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Date END) AS Date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Code END) AS Code1, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Date END) AS Date2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Code END) AS Code2, 
FROM Ranked
GROUP BY EventID;


Hi - for Event 3 - A13 is code2, not code1 - what is the business rule that determines this?

@Mr.Brownstone i have updated the question.

If you only need 2 codes in a row
you can use a GAPS And ISLAND approach
Where you add another column for the GROUP BY, so that all pair will be grouped to gether.
this is achieved by using the modulo of 2 on the row_number, so that it will pair to gether, which is achieved i the second CTE.
CREATE TABLE TableEvent (
  EventId INTEGER,
  Code VARCHAR(3),
  Date date
);

INSERT INTO TableEvent
  (EventId, Code, Date)
VALUES
  ('1', 'A12', '12/12/2020'),
  ('1', 'A13', '12/12/2020'),
    ('1', 'A14', '12/12/2020'),
  ('1', 'A15', '12/13/2020'),
  ('2', 'A12', '12/12/2020'),
  ('2', 'A13', '12/12/2020'),
  ('3', 'A13', '12/12/2020');

WITH Ranked AS (
    SELECT
        EventID,
        Date,
        Code ,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  EventID ORDER BY Date),
  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  EventID ORDER BY Date) % 2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END sum_
    FROM TableEvent
),
  CTE AS (
SELECT
          EventID,
        Date,
        Code ,
  rn,
  SUM(sum_) OVER(PARTITION BY EventID ORDER BY rn) sum_
  FROM ranked
  )
SELECT
    EventID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2  = 1 THEN Date END) AS Date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 1 THEN Code END) AS Code1, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn% 2  = 0 THEN Date END) AS Date2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2  = 0 THEN Code END) AS Code2 
FROM CTE
GROUP BY EventID, sum_
 ORDER BY EventID,MAX(rn) ;




EventID
Date1
Code1
Date2
Code2




1
2020-12-12
A12
2020-12-12
A13


1
2020-12-12
A14
2020-12-13
A15


2
2020-12-12
A12
2020-12-12
A13


3
2020-12-12
A13
null
null



Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.


fiddle

the number of codes varies from user to user it can reach upto 30, I would like to identify the maximum row count and then create the necessary columns.

The standard way of doing pivot tables - is to do them in the client, outside of the SQL.
If you really want to do inside SQL Server (cannot imagine real need for it), you can use pivoting functionality (read here). But you would still need to know beforehand a number of columns in the final result.
As a variant, you can do it in a batch or stored procedure (not a single select). In it, you will first find how many columns do you need. Construct a string with a select statement, with needed number of columns (based on pivot).
And finally, run this constructed statement as dynamic sql.
But it really is too much hustle with too little return. Much easier to do it on a client side.
